# Web page auto-scroll to input field

Tags: html

I embedded a `<iframe>` in the middle of my web page. However, there is a input field in that `<iframe>`, and every time I open the page it will automatically scroll/jump to that input field, which is at the middle of the page. That is annoying. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Make sure that input doesn't have the `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: @DrewKennedy The thing is that what I embedded in the `<iframe>` does not belong to me, so I can't control it...

Comment: Then you're probably screwed because of Same Origin Policy (prevent XSS).